# objectify filter empty values

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

How can I filter properly using Objectify 4 by several parameters, considering that some of those parameters can come empty, which would mean that I don't want to filter by those? 
Example:
Please consider I want to filter something like this:

```
      releases = ofy().load().type(Release.class)
                .filter("user.name", searchCriteria.getName())
                .filter("category", searchCriteria.getCategory())
                .filter("city", searchCriteria.getCity()).list();
```

In order to match with what I said above, I have now the following code, checking every time which of my parameters come empty so I don't put them on the filter in that case:

```
    if (!nameEmpty && !categoryEmpty && !cityEmpty) {
        releases = ofy().load().type(Release.class)
                .filter("user.name", searchCriteria.getName())
                .filter("category", searchCriteria.getCategory())
                .filter("city", searchCriteria.getCity()).list();
    } else if (!nameEmpty && !categoryEmpty) {
        releases = ofy().load().type(Release.class)
                .filter("user.name", searchCriteria.getName())
                .filter("category", searchCriteria.getCategory()).list();
    } else if (!nameEmpty && !cityEmpty) {
        releases = ofy().load().type(Release.class)
                .filter("user.name", searchCriteria.getName())
                .filter("city", searchCriteria.getCity()).list();
    } else if ...

       ...
```

How can I avoid this crappy way of filtering and make it with just one line (or a few) using Objectify 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Query<Release> query = ofy().load().type(Release.class);

if (!nameEmpty)
    query = query.filter("user.name", searchCriteria.getName());

if (!categoryEmpty)
    query = query.filter("category", searchCriteria.getCategory())

if (!cityEmpty)
    query = query.filter("city", searchCriteria.getCity());

releases = query.list();
```